# permalink doesn't work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have an issue with wordpress' permalink. So, there is a blog, there is a note/notes. when i click the link (with href=php the_permalink()) note is not shown but main page loads (not blog's page).
How can i fix it?

http://www.xn--d1aa4fb.xn--p1ai/blog/

I have another version of this site and it works properly:
http://dyadya.o98110rn.bget.ru/blog/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you run into a specific issue, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far, your problem, and how what should be the correct behavior. Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the CSS path in the inner pages.
You do not use the complete URL to call assets, like this:

```
http://......com/assets/css/your.css
```

You use the folder navigation, like this:

```
./assets/css/your.css
```

In your inner pages, the css file will not be found.
To solve this, add this tag inside your `<head></head>`

```
<base href="https://yoursite.com/"/>
```

With this, in yout inner pages, the pathi will not use the pages URL, will use the BASE HREF to look for the assets.

I hope it helps!

Comment: i agree about css. but content of the page is not right. I don't think this is about css. or can it?

Comment: In chrome, open [this page](http://www.дядя.рф/blog/2017/05/02/что-за-fade) and press CTRL + U to see the html code. In this page, you are not in the root, then if you call css like this: `assets/css/main.css` (see in the code), you will refer the css like this: `example.com/blog/2017/05/02/post/assets/css/main.css`. But the CSS is not there. The css is in `example.com/assets/css/main.css`. If you put the `<base>` tag inside `<head></head>`, the CSS (and other links) will use the base url to look for the files, insead the current url.

Comment: the main problem is i can't see the content of articles i added in wp-admin. So on blog page we see the list of articles but when we click on one of them we don't see it.

Comment: Ok, the language confused me. When I clicked in the post and the content was showed to me, I thought the content is that. But I was wrong. That page is 404 page, not the post page. How I dont understand the site language, I thought the content was loaded correctly. Then, do this: In your wordpress admin, go to: Settings > Permalink. Check DEFAULT and save. I suspect the server did not can understand some characters in the slug. But, lets see first this test. After that, I send others instructions.

Comment: Hey, I see you solve the problem.What was the problem?

Comment: It turned out the problem was because of moving site from apache to nginix. Administrator made some changes on the server side and everything is going right now. I asked him about changes he made and still waiting the answer.

Comment: Probably the rewrite rule was disabled. Happy it solved.